# Grouping similar items recursively

Tags: sql-server, recursion

I have been reading the following [Microsoft article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) on recursive queries using CTE and just can't seem to wrap my head around how to use it for group common items.

I have a table the contains the following columns:

- ID
- FirstName
- LastName
- DateOfBirth
- BirthCountry
- GroupID

What I need to do is start with the first person in the table and iterate through the table and find all the people that have the same (`LastName` and `BirthCountry`) or have the same (`DateOfBirth` and `BirthCountry`).

Now the tricky part is that I have to assign them the same `GroupID` and then for each person in that `GroupID`, I need to see if anyone else has the same information and then put the in the same `GroupID`.

I think I could do this with multiple cursors but it is getting tricky.

Here is sample data and output.

```
ID          FirstName  LastName   DateOfBirth BirthCountry GroupID
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ------------ -----------
1           Jonh       Doe        1983-01-01  Grand        100
2           Jack       Stone      1976-06-08  Grand        100
3           Jane       Doe        1982-02-08  Grand        100
4           Adam       Wayne      1983-01-01  Grand        100
5           Kay        Wayne      1976-06-08  Grand        100
6           Matt       Knox       1983-01-01  Hay          101
```

- John Doe and Jane Doe are in the same Group (100) because they have the same (LastName and BirthCountry).
- Adam Wayne is in Group (100) because he has the same (BirthDate and BirthCountry) as John Doe.
- Kay Wayne is in Group (100) because she has the same (LastName and BirthCountry) as Adam Wayne who is already in Group (100).
- Matt Knox is in a new group (101) because he does not match anyone in previous groups.
- Jack Stone is in a group (100) because he has the same (BirthDate and BirthCountry) as Kay Wayne who is already in Group (100).

Data scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE #Tbl(
    ID              INT,
    FirstName       VARCHAR(50),
    LastName        VARCHAR(50),
    DateOfBirth     DATE,
    BirthCountry    VARCHAR(50),
    GroupID         INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #Tbl VALUES
(1, 'Jonh', 'Doe',      '1983-01-01',   'Grand',    NULL),
(2, 'Jack', 'Stone',    '1976-06-08',   'Grand',    NULL),
(3, 'Jane', 'Doe',      '1982-02-08',   'Grand',    NULL),
(4, 'Adam', 'Wayne',    '1983-01-01',   'Grand',    NULL),
(5, 'Kay',  'Wayne',    '1976-06-08',   'Grand',    NULL),
(6, 'Matt', 'Knox',     '1983-01-01',   'Hay',      NULL);
```

Comment: WHY HV YOU POPULATED GROUPID ? Asumming groupid is the output you need,then from which groupid one should start ?100 ? why groupid should start from 100 ?

Comment: @goroth you've mentioned `CURSOR`. I believe it should be able to solve your problem. Have you already got something done with that?

Comment: At least don't try Cursor.

Comment: @ydoow I did get this to somewhat work with a double cursor and temp tables but it was very slow and messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with. I have rarely written recursive queries so it was some good practice for me. By the way Kay and Adam do not share a birth country in your sample data.

```
with data as (
    select
        LastName, DateOfBirth, BirthCountry,
        row_number() over (order by LastName, DateOfBirth, BirthCountry) as grpNum
    from T group by LastName, DateOfBirth, BirthCountry
), r as (
    select
        d.LastName, d.DateOfBirth, d.BirthCountry, d.grpNum,
        cast('|'  + cast(d.grpNum as varchar(8)) + '|' as varchar(1024)) as equ
    from data as d
    union all
    select
        d.LastName, d.DateOfBirth, d.BirthCountry, r.grpNum,
        cast(r.equ + cast(d.grpNum as varchar(8)) + '|' as varchar(1024))
    from r inner join data as d
            on      d.grpNum > r.grpNum
               and charindex('|' + cast(d.grpNum as varchar(8)) + '|', r.equ) = 0
               and (d.LastName = r.LastName or d.DateOfBirth = r.DateOfBirth)
               and  d.BirthCountry = r.BirthCountry
), g as (
    select LastName, DateOfBirth, BirthCountry, min(grpNum) as grpNum
    from r group by LastName, DateOfBirth, BirthCountry
)
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by g.grpNum) + 100 as GroupID
from T as t 
    inner join g
        on      g.LastName = t.LastName
            and g.DateOfBirth = t.DateOfBirth
            and g.BirthCountry = t.BirthCountry
```

For the recursion to terminate it's necessary to keep track of the equivalences (via string concatenation) so that at each level it only needs to consider newly discovered equivalences (or connections, transitivities, etc.) Notice that I've avoided using the word *group* to avoid bleeding into the `GROUP BY` concept.

http://rextester.com/edit/TVRVZ10193

*EDIT:* I used an almost arbitrary numbering for the equivalences but if you wanted them to appear in a sequence based on the lowest ID with each block that's easy to do. Instead of using `row_number()` say `min(ID) as grpNum` presuming, of course, that `ID`s are unique.

Comment: This never finishes running on the set of data I have. About 500,000 records.

Comment: @goroth I believe I figured out the right way to do this. Hopefully it will work for you this time.

Comment: While the performance was much better, it does not put Jack Stone in the 100 group. Looks like it does not recursive each time it finds a match.

Comment: Actually I was wrong. If I change the + 100 to + 99 as the GroupID then Jack Stone is in the correct group of 100. I'm still testing on larger datasets. I will let you know.

Comment: @goroth Very odd since that 100 really shouldn't change any of the logic.

Comment: @goroth I hope you've noticed that I didn't attempt to match your numbering scheme exactly since you didn't specify what ordering you wanted. The important thing is that they end under the same groupid though.

Answer (score 1):

I assume groupid is the output you want which start from 100.
Even if groupid come from another table,then it is no problem.

Firstly,sorry for my "No cursor comments".Cursor or RBAR operation is require for this task.In fact after a very long time i met such requirement which took so long and I use RBAR operation.

if tommorrow i am able to do using SET BASE METHOD,then I will come and edit it.

Most importantly using RBAR operation make the script more understanding and I think it wil work for other sample data too.
Also give feedback about the performance and how it work with other sample data.

Alsi in my script you note that id are not in serial,and it do not matter,i did this in order to test.

I use print for debuging purpose,you can remove it.

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE(
    ID              INT,
    FirstName       VARCHAR(50),
    LastName        VARCHAR(50),
    DateOfBirth     DATE,
    BirthCountry    VARCHAR(50),
    GroupID         INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @Tbl VALUES
(1, 'Jonh', 'Doe',      '1983-01-01',   'Grand',    NULL) ,
(2, 'Jack', 'Stone',    '1976-06-08',   'Grand',    NULL),
(3, 'Jane', 'Doe',      '1982-02-08',   'Grand',    NULL),
(4, 'Adam', 'Wayne',    '1983-01-01',   'Grand',    NULL),
(5, 'Kay',  'Wayne',    '1976-06-08',   'Grand',    NULL),
(6, 'Matt', 'Knox',     '1983-01-01',   'Hay',      NULL),
(7, 'Jerry', 'Stone',   '1976-06-08',   'Hay',      NULL)


DECLARE @StartGroupid INT = 100
DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE @Groupid INT
DECLARE @Maxid INT
DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @MinGroupID int=@StartGroupid
DECLARE @MaxGroupID int=@StartGroupid
DECLARE @LastGroupID int
SELECT @maxid = max(id)
FROM @tbl

WHILE (@i <= @maxid)
BEGIN
    SELECT @id = id
        ,@Groupid = Groupid
    FROM @Tbl a
    WHERE id = @i

    if(@Groupid is not null and @Groupid<@MinGroupID)
    set @MinGroupID=@Groupid
    if(@Groupid is not null and @Groupid>@MaxGroupID)
    set @MaxGroupID=@Groupid
    if(@Groupid is not null)
    set @LastGroupID=@Groupid

    UPDATE A
    SET groupid =case 
            when @id=1 and  b.groupid is null then @StartGroupid 
            when @id>1 and  b.groupid is null then @MaxGroupID+1--(Select max(groupid)+1 from @tbl where id<@id)
            when @id>1 and  b.groupid is not null then @MinGroupID --(Select min(groupid) from @tbl where id<@id)
    end
    FROM @Tbl A
    INNER JOIN @tbl B ON b.id = @ID
    WHERE (
            (
                a.BirthCountry = b.BirthCountry
                and a.DateOfBirth = b.dateofbirth
                )
            or (a.LastName = b.LastName and a.BirthCountry = b.BirthCountry)
                 or (a.LastName = b.LastName and a.dateofbirth = b.dateofbirth)
            )

--if(@id=7) --@id=2,@id=3 and so on (for debug
--break

    SET @i = @i + 1
    SET @ID = @I
END

SELECT * 
FROM @Tbl
```

Alternate Method but still it return 56,000 rows without rownum=1.See if it work with other sample data or see if you can further optimize it.

```
;with CTE as
(
    select a.ID,a.FirstName,a.LastName,a.DateOfBirth,a.BirthCountry
    ,@StartGroupid GroupID 
    ,1 rn
    FROM @Tbl A where a.id=1


UNION ALL

Select a.ID,a.FirstName,a.LastName,a.DateOfBirth,a.BirthCountry


 ,case when ((a.BirthCountry = b.BirthCountry and a.DateOfBirth = b.dateofbirth)
            or (a.LastName = b.LastName and a.BirthCountry = b.BirthCountry)
            or (a.LastName = b.LastName and a.dateofbirth = b.dateofbirth)
            ) then b.groupid  else b.groupid+1 end
    , b.rn+1
    FROM @tbl A
   inner join CTE B on a.id>1 

   where b.rn<@Maxid

)
,CTE1 as
(select * ,row_number()over(partition by id order by groupid )rownum 
from CTE )

select * from cte1
where rownum=1
```

Comment: It does not put Jack Stone in the 100 group. Looks like it does not recursive each time it finds a match

Comment: very late reply.why Jack Stone should be in 100 group ?

Comment: Jack Stone has the same (BirthDate and BirthCountry) as Kay Wayne and Kay Wayne is in group 100 because she has the same (LastName and BirthCountry) as Adam Wayne and Adam Wayne is in group 100 because he has the same (BirthDate and BirthCountry) as John Doe.  It is a very confusing chain.

Comment: @goroth,yeah my answere is wrong according to your logic.suppose there are only top 3-4 record in table then what will be that group of id=2 ?101 ? So this group id is not constant. it will be calculated each time.ARE YOU SURE,ABOUT THE LOGIC ?

Comment: Yes I am sure about the logic. This is a chain of people that are similar to each other. The example I gave is only for demo purpose. In real world data I am trying to find similar patterns of data.

Comment: @goroth ,so did you try my latest script ? is it working .or why not working ?

Comment: This will not work either. Basically when it finds a match, it must go back to the top of the list each time and see if there are any other matches while still keeping the same group id on each recursive loop. Your logic works great on the first pass but once the chain goes 2+ levels deep it fails because it does not keep the same group ID. The second "where" clause needs to loop again for each record. Assume there is a "Jerry Stone 1976-06-08 Hay". This person would also be in group 100 since John Stone is in group 100 and they both have the same lastname / birth date but diff birth country.

Comment: Your logic puts "Jerry Stone" in group 101 with "Matt Knox" but the only thing they have in common is the birth country. They must have at least 2 pieces of data in common. (lastname / birthdate, or lastname / birthcountry, or birthdate / birthcountry)

Comment: you didn't write any thing about lastname / birthdate.i am missing this piece in my script because earlleir you didn't explain anything about it.

Comment: @goroth , See my latest script.Suppose ,max recird is 7 then it will loop 7 times.and no need of relooping as per my logic.uncomment that 2 lines in order to debug and understand my logic.so far whatever you hv explain and according to sample data,i hv cover everything.Check and let me,if my script work that means i hv understood the requirement fully and think of optimising it.

Comment: The code works fine but is about 10 times slower than the code listed in the recursive CTE from shawnt00. My guess is the MIN / MAX functions are causing slowness but I do like your approach since it is easier to read / understand. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @goroth , wc. check my alternate solution.But still it is not best.

Comment: @goroth, Also check first methods,it must be definetly faster than earlier .Now your problem seem easier day by day though  we are not able to put the logic in SET BASED Approach

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can run it in this way

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
GROUP BY
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    GroupID
HAVING COUNT(GroupID) >= 2
ORDER BY GroupID
```